# newbies issue on installing django with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

Trying out for the first time pythons django I'm facing the following problem. I have bee deploying with `apache wsgi` and using the git trunk installed under `/var/tmp/django-trunk`. Than I was creating my first app under

List item

```
 /var/www/pi
        --pi
          ---setting.py
           ....
        --pi_django
          ---admin.py
          ---views.py
          ....
        --manage.py
```

setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

than I was running from `/var/www/pi python manage.py syncdb`

Tables were created

However when I try to access backend example.site/admin
I get

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://example.site/admin/
Django Version: 1.7.dev20131123185020
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1046, 'No database selected')
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/var/www/pi',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg',
 '/var/tmp/django-trunk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time:    Sun, 24 Nov 2013 11:41:25 +0000
```

Comment: Have you installed Mysql? ;)

Comment: as I said mysql tables are created under mydatabase on python manage.py syncdb

Comment: restarting couple of time apache works